# How to replace a className part with JavaScript Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I've a simple `div`with various class attributs:

```
<div id="divId" class="anInformationIWantToGet aClassUsedForCss"></div>
```

I want to programatically get the `anInformationIWantToGet` class which vary, the problem should be easy because others classes are known, so a Regex like following should do the job:

```
var anInformationIWantToGet  = div.className.replace(/(\s*(aClassUsedForCss)?\s*)/, '');
```

But it doesn't work and I don't understant why... What did I miss?

I create a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arruumep/1/) to test the problem.

PS : my browser is Firefox17.

Comment: Firefox 17 is ancient. You should upgrade ASAP.

Comment: Why not use [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)?

Comment: @Quentin I completely agree, but it's not in my hands unfortunately...

Comment: @RGraham Because I thought I could to it with 1 line with Regex. If I found no good solution I'll loop over classList, sure.

Comment: One hint from me: never write a regex all parts of which are optional. Use anchors at least, e.g.: `\s*(?:hover)?\s*$`

Answer (score 1):

Try this
Change you below code

```
var anInformationIWantToGet  = div.className.replace(/(\s*(aClassUsedForCss)?\s*)/, '');
```

To

```
var anInformationIWantToGet  = div.className.replace(/(\s*(aClassUsedForCss)?\s*)/g, '');
```

put g in regular expression.

And working updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/saikiran_vsk/arruumep/2/)

Ask for more, If above is not working/Understood.

Answer (score 0):

```
/(\s*(aClassUsedForCss)?\s*)/
                       ^
```

You've made the class name you are looking for optional, so the first match will be the 0 or more white space at the beginning of the string.

Remove the `?` and/or make it a global regex (by appending `g`).

Answer (score 0):

This will work

[FiddleChanged](https://jsfiddle.net/arruumep/1/)

```
function replaceClass(){
    /* Should not output 'hover' */
   var reqdClasName = div.className.match(/(\S*)\s*hover\s*/)[1];
   div.className.replace(reqdClasName, '');
   result.innerHTML = reqdClasName;   
}
```

Oops i had missed the replacing part. I ve updated

[UpdatedFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arruumep/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Be aware of replacing white spaces. Try [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/arruumep/3/).

```
var anInformationIWantToGet  = div.className.replace(/(\s*(?:aClassUsedForCss)\s*)/, ' ').trim();
```

[Correct example](https://jsfiddle.net/arruumep/4/).

Answer (score 0):

We will also change it by just adding class which we required and remove the remaining like that way.

```
$("#myDiv").attr("class","aClassUsedForCss");
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/arruumep/5/)